# Shiny: How to change the background colour of a button while it is clicked

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to change the colour of a button using css in R Shiny. The default bootstrap styling seems to colour the button light grey when it is pressed (i.e. **during** the click), but I want it to be green. I believe this is done with the `:active` pseudo-class selector but it doesn't work: the button is still light grey when depressed but the lime colouring of the button does work.

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
        theme = "style.css",
        actionButton("my-button", "Click me")
    )
```

style.css

```
.btn, .btn:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Try `.btn:active {background: green !important;}`

Comment: Thank you that works. If you would like to make an answer out of it, I will accept it

Comment: the important thing is that it works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

We can maybe use `shinyjs` to do that:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("my_button", "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$my_button,{
        runjs('document.getElementById("my_button").style.backgroundColor = "red";')
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

or we can also use `shinyBS` package to update the button:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
    bsButton('my_button', "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$my_button,{
        updateButton(session,'my_button',style = "warning")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:focus` instead of `:active`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was clear enough. I am looking to change the colour during the click.